# what files are included when using maven deploy?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I want to run maven deploy to a project, I understand the deploy packages the project as a jar and puts this jar on a remote repository, however I was wondering, in project section of Intellij there are several files including reports generated when I run my code, so does the deployed jar include those files? for example: report.json , report.xml. etc...
If anyone can tell what exactly does the deployed jar include that'd be great!

Comment: If you run a Maven goal - then this is not related to the IDE. Maven will package the jar according to your Maven configuration. Normally this could be the compiled sources from the src/main/java src/test/java directories and the resources from the src/main/resources src/test/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If anyone can tell what exactly does the deployed jar include that'd be great!

Here's the [official doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) of what you're interested in.

It says that `mvn deploy` does the following ...

> deploy:deploy is used to automatically install the artifact, its pom and the attached artifacts produced by a particular project. Most if not all of the information related to the deployment is stored in the project's pom.

So what does it mean concretely ... well, we can look at an [example artifact](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/activeio/activeio/2.0/) the maven central repo.

Here's what we see ...

```
activeio-2.0-r118.jar                             2005-11-22 02:00    239185      
activeio-2.0-r118.jar.md5                         2005-11-22 02:00        32      
activeio-2.0-r118.jar.sha1                        2005-11-22 02:00        40      
activeio-2.0.pom                                  2005-11-22 02:00       148      
activeio-2.0.pom.md5                              2005-11-22 02:00        32      
activeio-2.0.pom.sha1                             2005-11-22 02:00        40      
maven-metadata.xml                                2005-11-22 02:00       113      
maven-metadata.xml.md5                            2005-11-22 02:00        77      
maven-metadata.xml.sha1                           2005-11-22 02:00       132
```

We have ...

1. `jar` file. Needed for the thing to work.
2. `pom.xml` for this dependency. Needed to download transitive dependencies
3. Metadata file
4. Hashes `.md5` and `.sha1` which allow to validate the integrity of the other files

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my question, I meant what the jar file specifically contains?
for the example you gave what the activeio-2.0-r118.jar contain? so before running deploy to generate this jar what files of project structure in Intellij were taken into this jar? I hope its clearer now

Comment: The jar will contain the output of the `mvn package` command. This can be configured via plugins, etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974882/what-is-correct-internal-structure-of-jar-file) is what typically goes in there. For your specific case, you can create a jar via `mvn package` command, go to the `target` directory, unzip it and see what's inside